# Creating a loopback device in lio scsi target

Tags: linux, iscsi

I am using the Linux LIO package to create a loopback device for a backstore.  I am using "targetcli" utility to issue the following commands mentioned at site - http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Loopback  :

```
/backstores/fileio> create  dev_file_disk file_disk 10mb
/loopback> create
Created target naa.5001405f29525ad4.
```

However, I see the fileio backstore created in "deactivated" state:

```
| o- fileio .......................... [Storage Objects: 1]
| | o- dev_file_disk ................. [file_disk (10.0MiB)
                                        write-back deactivated]
```

How can I activate the fileio backstore (dev_file_disk)?  My
understanding, if all is setup right (fileio backstore is active), a new
entry /dev/sdx  will be created.  Is that right?

I have a related question.  If I create multiple fileio and/or block
backstore.  Is there a way I can control which of the fileio/blockio
are created as loopback, rather than all of them.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I had to go into the loopback target / lun ("cd naa.500140582a838aa2/luns/") and then manually issue a "create" command for each backstore for which I wanted to created a loopback device.
It would be nice/helpful if this critical step was mentioned in the wiki.

Comment: It seems that the wiki explicitly says it's not required - "_targetcli_ automatically assigns the default ID '0' to the LUN" - but I had to do it manually as you suggest too.  Perhaps it's a difference in the versions of `targetcli`?  I'm using version 2.1.fb46-6 on CentOS 7.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1297792 reports this as a bug.